# Subtracting Variants

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting Variants to subtract. I am pulling data from a spreadsheet and if one cell states a phrase then I need the code to subtract one cell from another. If the cell does not state a phrase then I need it to copy one cell to another. I can get the code to run but nothing happens.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Variant, a As Integer, B As String

    'getting values for data
    x = Range("D2:D48").Value
    y = Range("I2:I48").Value
    z = Range("E2:E48").Value

    B = "Total ISU Days: "
    'The the cells are empty then subtract. This is not what I wanted to do but I can't think of extracting strings from variants. 
    If IsEmpty(Range("D2:D48").Value) = True Then
        a = y - z
    End If

    Range("N2:N48").Value = a
    Range("M2:M48").Value = B

End Sub
```

Comment: You must loop the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> x = Range("D2:D48").Value
> y = Range("I2:I48").Value
> z = Range("E2:E48").Value
> ```

A `Variant` contains metadata about its *subtype*. In this case, `x`, `y`, and `z` are all *arrays of variants*.

> ```
> a = y - z
> ```

The right-hand side of this expression simply cannot be evaluated, because `{array1} - {array2}` means nothing: operators (arithmetic *or* logical) work off *values*, not *array of values*.

What is `a` supposed to be? It's declared `As Integer`, so its value is capped at 32,767 (should probably be a `Long`). If you mean to add up all the values in `y` and subtract that total from the sum of all values in `z`, then you need to be more explicit about how you do that - you could use `Application[.WorksheetFunction].Sum` to add things up:

```
sumOfY = Application.Sum(Range("I2:I48"))
sumOfZ = Application.Sum(Range("E2:E48"))
a = sumOfY - sumOfZ
```

And then...

> ```
> Range("N2:N48").Value = a
> ```

That will put the value of `a` in every single cell in the `N2:N48` range - is that really what you mean to do?

Or maybe you meant to do this instead?

```
Range("N2:N48").Formula = "=IF(D2="""",I2-E2,0)"
```

That would make each cell in `N2:N48` calculate the difference between `I` and `E` for each row where `D` is empty... and there's not really any need for any VBA code to do this.

Comment: Range("N2:N48").Formula = "=IF(D2="""",I2-E2,0)" This is what I was going for. I have not tried to get it done yet. I am creating a button for a report that will automatically run this for me every week. I am curious, why do you think there is no need for any VBA code to do that function? I am new to VBA so I am using this as more of a stepping stone on integrating some form of programming within my current job that I don't get any experience from in that way.

Comment: Because unless VBA code is generating the entire worksheet, then the formula can be entered directly in column N - say in `N2`, put `=IF(D2="", I2-E2,"")`, fill down, and call it a day ;-)

Comment: haha okay I see. I tried something similar to that the first time but thought it would be easier to install a button that would do this for me. I have to pull this report from a reporting website every week. Now I am understanding a little bit more about what exactly VBA is for. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @mmrz there's nothing wrong with having a button that adds a computed column to an existing worksheet - but VBA can be used and abused for literally anything, including and not limited to downloading the file from the reporting website (is that a SSRS portal?), prompting and providing any report parameters, tweaking the resulting document to death, and emailing the modified file to a mailing list.

Comment: Yes it is an SSRS portal. I could download the report from the portal using VBA?

Comment: Probably, yes. But, if the SSRS report doesn't include the data you need, the simplest solution would be to tweak and re-deploy the report itself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify a bit the task and say that the idea is to substract the values in `Range("C1:C6")` from the corresponding values in the left - `Range("B1:B6")`. Then write the corresponding results in column `E`:

[image]

Of course, this would be done only in case that all values in column `A` are empty. This is one way to do it:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim checkNotEmpty As Boolean: checkNotEmpty = False
    Dim substractFrom As Range: Set substractFrom = Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B6")
    Dim substractTo As Range: Set substractTo = Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C6")

    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(substractFrom.Cells.Count - 1)

    Dim areCellsEmpty As Boolean
    For Each MyCell In substractFrom
        If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then checkNotEmpty = True
    Next

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(result) + 1 To UBound(result) + 1
        result(i - 1) = substractFrom.Cells(i) - substractTo.Cells(i)
    Next

    Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Resize(UBound(result) + 1) = Application.Transpose(result)

End Sub
```

- The code could be improved further, saving all ranges to an Array, but it works quite ok so far.
- The part with the `+1` and `-1` in the `For-loop` is needed as a workaround:

  `For i = LBound(result) + 1 To UBound(result) + 1
      result(i - 1) = substractFrom.Cells(i) - substractTo.Cells(i)
  Next`

because the arrays start from index `0`, but the `Cells` in a range start with row `1`.

- `Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Resize(UBound(result) + 1) = Application.Transpose(result)` is needed, to write the values of the `result` array to the column `E`, without defining the length of the range in `E`.

Comment: A 2D variant array pulled from `Range.Value` will be 1-based "out of convenience" though. Wouldn't it be simpler to declare an explicit lower bound of `1` for `result`? `ReDim result(LBound(subtractFrom) To UBound(subtractFrom))` would eliminate the need to worry about array bounds and +1/-1 offsets.

Comment: That said, I've no idea what the OP is *actually* trying to do, but I get the feeling they don't need any VBA to do it...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - The 2D variant array was the reason I provided a screenshot and declared the ranges explicitly. Indeed, `ReDim result(LBound(subtractFrom) To UBound(subtractFrom))`, but I have the feeling from the question that the OP does not "feel" quite well around ranges and arrays, thus tried to provide really the smallest uncomplicated thing that works.